# Restrict a dataframe based on age at measurement

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, missing-data

I have a dataframe in long format with repeated data on id, age and height. How can I restrict the dataset so that it includes only people with at least 1 measurement taken from age 5 onwards and also at least 1 measurement between age 9 and 20 years.

(So if a person has only 1 height measurement and it is measured before age 9 they will be excluded (because they don't also have another measure between 9 and 20)

```
# LOAD SITAR PACKAGE WITH EXAMPLE DATASET 
library(sitar)

data <- berkeley %>% select(id, age, height)
summary(data)

#THIS RESTRICTS TO HEIGHTS TAKEN >= age 5: HOW TO ALSO RESTICT TO >=1 MEASURE BETWEEN AGE 9 and 20?
data <- data %>% filter(age!="NA" & height!="NA" & age>=5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(any(age  > 5 & between(age, 9,20)))
```

But it seems in your example all the `id`s satisfies both the criterias.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .SD[any(age > 5 & between(age, 9, 20))], id]
```